# for each and http get with angular

Tags: angular, foreach

i am looking for a way to get a query during a foreach with angular.
I have a table like this:

```
players = [
{
  id: 'af948a0a-66be-44b1-af85-7ccd1a289df0',
  pseudo: 'DocEo.AG',
  age: '31',
  twitch: '',
  youtube: false,
  facebook: false,
  twitter: '',
  stats: [],

}];
```

I would like at the foreach, get the stats via the id of the person and push in my table, but for the moment without success.
Here is my code for the moment that does not work.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.players = this.teamService.players;

    this.statUser();  
}

statUser() {
    this.players.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element.id);
        this.getStats('element.id');
    });
}

getStats(idUser) {
    this.http.get(this.urlIdTest + idUser).subscribe((data) => {
        this.getStat = data;
    });
}
```

EDIT: I have a new problem, everything works fine but I have this error message in the console:http://prntscr.com/p2kvu8
My array: http://prntscr.com/p2kwpf

Comment: Why are you passing the string `'element.id'` to getStats()? How about passing `element` instead (i.e. the user object), get the stats for that user, and update the user with the stats you obtained?

Comment: That's what I want to do, but I can not find the right syntax or the right way to do it ...
Because if I try   this.getStats (element.id);   it does not work

Comment: Again, what you should pass is `element`, not `element.id`. You want to pass the user object, not its ID.

Comment: Do not do this. Making multiple http calls like this will not be good for your application's performance. Instead maybe modify your API to accept a a string of ids separated by a `,` or `;` as your query params and use `join(",")` or `join(";")` to join the ids before you send the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing id as `'element.id'` (string) modify code like:

```
...
statUser() {
    this.players.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element.id);
        this.getStats(element.id);
    });
}
...
```

**Update 1**

You can optimize your code by passing complete object and then assign stats in it.

```
statUser() {
    this.players.forEach((player) => {
        this.getStats(player);
    });
}

getStats(player) {
    this.http.get(this.urlIdTest + player.id).subscribe((data) => {
        player.stats = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: @Eolynas yes that's why I updated my answer you can send complete object and assign stats in it in subscriber.

Comment: Perfect it works ....
I just had a problem with the synthaxe .... thank you very much

EDIT: What is the difference between: 
this.players.forEach(function(element) {
        this.getStats(element.id);
    });

and 

statUser() {
    this.players.forEach((player) => {
        this.getStats(player);
    });
}

Comment: "thank you, on the other hand this.getStat does not return anything" reason within my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just a little side note, please avoid vanilla functions within Angular Components. Always use Arrow-functions. Vanilla functions change the scope of `this`

```
this.players.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element.id);
        this.getStats('element.id'); // the this here
    });

this.players.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.id);
        this.getStats('element.id'); // is not the same here
    });
```

Comment: I think you mean arrow functions, not Array-functions :). And really, this should be a comment...

Comment: Yeah thanks of course I mean arrow functions ;-) edited